# Resizing image prevented

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I can't figure out why, but the background image resize is prevented by something.

I've the following code that adds image to div's background and I'm willing to show the whole image, not just the center of it.
Some how the image is zooming in and I would like to change that to full image view.

```
#section1{
  background-image: url(http://freevectorsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Abstract-Hi-Tech-Background.jpg);
  background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1000px;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="section1" class="section">
      <div class="text">
        <p>My Work</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/oNgwpjp)

How can I use `background-size` to view the whole image and not just part of it?

Comment: Hello, the code is wrong in more than one place. You could use everywhere contain instead of cover for background attributes, and you should get rid of that transform: traslate attribute as well and the hardcoded 1000px there. And use an 1920 width image for all resolutions.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu the transform is used to different part of the code that I've found it irrelevant for the question, also the method I use is part of another code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#section1{
  background-image: url(http://freevectorsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Abstract-Hi-Tech-Background.jpg);
  background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1);
  z-index:-1;
}
#section1 .text{
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: That did worked! can you explain me more what was wrong?

Comment: transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2); that a problem. it scale 2 times

Answer (score 2):

According to code you provided, height of the div isn't set manually, so its height is auto and equals to size(height) of its content. The div contains only child div and paragraph so it's size is small.

So you could try this:

```
<div id="section1" class="section">
    <div class="text">
       <p>My Work</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#section1{
  background-image: url(http://freevectorsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Abstract-Hi-Tech-Background.jpg);
  background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  height: 100vh; /*This equals to whole viewport height, but you can try any size you want*/
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I've tried to change width and height, neither worked.